# Hiding or Deleting the "Ship to a Different Address?" checkbox in Woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking for a working solution to either hide or delete the "Ship to a different address?" checkbox in Woocommerce checkout page in Wordpress, but I haven't figured out how to do so, so far.
Is there any way to do this?

By the way, I use Sahifa theme.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is an option that allows you to remove this checkbox along with shipping section. Go to

> Administration->Woocommerce->Settings->Shipping->Shipping Options

and find `Shipping Destination`, and make sure that `Force shipping to the customer billing address` checkbox is checked.

Comment: You write faster than me Stan !

Comment: when i do this, the entire layout got messed up. i should hide it with a remove_action or filter

Comment: Is there any programmatic way to do this? In purpose of creating plugin.

Answer (score 21):

In case someone wants to remove it using code, it is doable by adding this filter to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Simply add this code to `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', '__return_false' );
```